# Computing the last 4 digits of $2013^{2014^{2015}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is an old exam question from the introduction to abstract algebra course I took 7 years ago.

I tried using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. I computed that $2013^{2014^{2015}} \equiv 1 \mod 16$.
However, I have troubles computing $2013^{2014^{2015}} \mod 625$. This makes me wonder if this is the right approach.

Any hints would be appreciated.In this course, I learned about CRT, Eulers and Fermats congruence. These were the results concerning modular arithmetic I learned...

Comment: Questions of the form $a^{(b^c)}$ can usually be solved by calculating $b^c \bmod \varphi(n)$.

Comment: @HereToRelax that is what I tried. Unfortunatly, this means computing mod 200, which does not make things much easier (I did the computations and large exponents remained)

Comment: to calculate it mod 200 you can calculate it mod 8 and mod 25, but calculating it mod is very easy. For mod 25 you can use eulers theorem once again. Oh, it appears there was a typo somewhere and the mod is a bit larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so $10^4 = 2^4 5^4$ and $\phi(2^4) = 2^3 = 8$ and $\phi(8) = 4$

So $2013^{2014^{2015}}\equiv (2013\% 16)^{(2014\%8)^{2015\%4}}\equiv (-3)^{6^{3}\% 8}\equiv (-3)^0\equiv 1 \pmod {16}$

And $\phi (5^4) = 5^3=125;$ and $\phi (125)= 25$.

Okay $2015\equiv 15\pmod {25}$ and $2014\equiv 14\pmod {125}$ and $2013 \equiv 138\pmod 625$.

So we have to calculate $138^{14^{15}}\pmod{625}$

Welp.... $14^{15}\pmod {125}$ first.

$(3\cdot 5-1)^{15}\pmod 125=\sum C_k 3^55^k(-1)^{15-k} \equiv {15\choose 2}3^2\cdot 5^2(-1)^{13} + 15\cdot 3(-1)^{14} + (-1)^{15}\pmod {125}\equiv -9\frac {15\cdot 16}2\cdot 25 + 45 - 1\equiv 44\pmod {125}$

So we have to figure $138^{44}\pmod {625}$.

Continue with the binomial theorem

$(28\cdot 5- 2)^{44} \pmod {625} \equiv 28^3\cdot 5^3\cdot {44\choose 3}(-2)^{41} + 28^2\cdot 5^2{44 \choose 2}(-2)^{42} + 28\cdot 5\cdot 44\cdot (-2)^{43}+(-2)^{44}\pmod {625}\equiv $

$28^3\cdot{44 \choose 3}\cdot (-2)^{41}\pmod 5\equiv 3^3\cdot\frac {42\cdot 43\cdot 44}7\cdot(-2)\equiv 2\cdot (7\cdot 3\cdot(-1))\cdot -2\equiv-1 \pmod 5$

$28^2\cdot {44\choose 2}\cdot (-2)^{42}\pmod{25}\equiv 3^2\cdot \frac{43\cdot 44}2\cdot 2^2\equiv 9\cdot 43\cdot 22\cdot 4\equiv 36\cdot (-7)\cdot(-3)\equiv 11\cdot 21 \equiv 11\cdot (-4)\equiv 6\pmod {25}$

And $28\cdot 44\cdot (-2)^43 \pmod {125} \equiv (25+3)(45-1) \cdot ((-2)^7)^6(-2)\equiv 113\cdot 128^6\cdot (-2)\equiv 24\cdot 3^6\equiv (25-1)(25+2)^2\equiv -4\pmod{125}$.

And $(-2)^44 \equiv (2^7)^6\cdot 2 \equiv (125 +3)^6\cdot 2\equiv 2(6\cdot 125\cdot 3^5 + 3^6)\equiv 2(125\cdot 243 + 729)\equiv 2(125\cdot 3 + 105)\equiv 125 + 210\equiv 335\pmod {625}$

So.... $138^{44}\pmod{625}\equiv -125 + 6\cdot 25 -4\cdot 125 +335\equiv 485\pmod {625}$

But obviously I made arithmetic errors as it is utterly impossible for me to do that much arithmetic and *not* make an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of separating the $\bmod 10000$ result into $\bmod 16$ and $\bmod 625$ results and recombining with the Chinese Remainder Theorem is fine. The totient value for $625$, $\varphi(625)=500$ so we can treat the expression as $$2013^{2014^{2015}}\equiv 138^{2014^{2015}\bmod 500}\equiv 138^{14^{2015}\bmod 500}\bmod 625$$ and then the reduced-totient [Carmichael function $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) gives us the least universal period of $\lambda(500)=100$ so $$2013^{2014^{2015}} \equiv 138^{14^{15}\bmod 500}\bmod 625$$

Then working $\bmod 500$,
$14^2 = 196$,
$14^4\equiv 196^2 =(200-4)^2\equiv -1600+16 \equiv -84 \equiv -6\cdot 14$,
$14^8\equiv -84^2= (16-100)^2\equiv 256-3200\equiv 56\equiv 4\cdot 14$ and
$14^{15}\equiv 14\cdot 196 \cdot -84 \cdot 56\equiv -24\cdot 14^5\equiv 144\cdot 14^2\equiv (150-6)(200-4)\equiv -600-1200+24\equiv 224$

So we have $$2013^{2014^{2015}} \equiv 138^{224}\bmod 625$$

which is nearly as tricky as it seems, coming out via [exponentiation-by-squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) at $611\equiv -14 \bmod 625$.
$$\begin{array}{c}
e & 138^e\bmod 625\\ \hline
224 & 611 & \mathit{\text{square}} \\
112 & 106 & \mathit{\text{square}} \\
56 & 441 & \mathit{\text{square}} \\
28 & 21 & \mathit{\text{square}} \\
14 & 164 & \mathit{\text{square}} \\
7 & 142 & \mathit{\text{square & multiply}} \\
3 & 572 & \mathit{\text{square & multiply}} \\
1 & 138 & \mathit{\text{initial value}}\\
\phantom{\Rightarrow}\Downarrow\underset{\Rightarrow}{} & \underset{\Rightarrow}{}\Uparrow \phantom{\Rightarrow} & \Uparrow\\
\end{array}
$$
Also to check your result on the $\bmod 16$ side, $\lambda(16) = 4$ so $2013^{2014^{2015}} \equiv 13^{2^{2015}} \equiv (13^4)^x \equiv 1 \bmod 16$, as you had.
*(I was earlier bringing the second exponent value down to $1$ which was a mistake, as it often is)*

Then to hurry-up the CRT a little, $625\equiv 1 \bmod 16$ so we need $15\cdot 625-14\equiv 1\bmod 16$ and $\fbox{9361}$ is our answer.

Comment: I checked my answer $\mod 16$ using Wolfram, which gave $1$ as a result... Also, according to wolfram the answer should be 9361. Thanks for your answer, I'll take a closer look!

Comment: @Student Reviewed this and found my error, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Apply Euler,  so you can reduce the exponent $2014^{2015} \bmod \varphi (10000)=4000$.  (Get $224$.)

Now apply CRT to $2013^{224}\bmod10000$.  (Ans: $9361$.)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete solution, the following approach significantly simplifies the problem:

To calculate $2013^{2014^{2015}}$ modulo $5^4$, to use Euler's theorem you want to calculate $2014^{2015}$ modulo $\varphi(5^4)=2^2\cdot 5^3$.

Clearly it is $0$ modulo $2^2$. Now, to calculate $2014^{2015}$ modulo $5^3$, again using Euler's theorem and since $\varphi(5^3)=100$, we have $2014^{2015}\equiv14^{2015}\equiv14^{15}\equiv99\pmod{5^3}$. Putting this together, we obtain $2014^{2015}\equiv 224\pmod{2^2\cdot5^3}$. Thus, we have $2013^{2014^{2015}}\equiv2013^{224}\equiv138^{224}\pmod{5^4}$.

Comment: You can finish this off by doing exponentiation by squaring